# Is there a common notation for characteristic subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, characteristic-subgroups

There is a common notation in group theory for normal subgroups. Also there is a notation for subnormal subgroups. But quite often we deal with characteristic subgroups. So, my question

> Is there a common notation for characteristic subgroups? And if there is no common notation, is this a good idea to denote a characteristic subgroup $H$ of group $G$ in the following manner $H \operatorname{char} G$?

Comment: I encountered the notation that you proposed in "[An introduction to the Theory of Groups](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387942858)" of Joseph J. Rotman. So feel free to use it, I would say.

Comment: I also think that $H \operatorname{char} G$ is most widely understood. Just as an addition: My algebra professor many years ago used a symbol derived from the "normal subgroup" triangle, but with an extra vertical line on the right (something like $\triangleleft\small|$). I kind of liked that symbol, but I have never seen it in use since (and LaTeX and MathJax don't support it either), so I believe my professer just made it up.

Comment: I was taught when writing maths to always say something (within reason) to back up your notation. So for example, don't write "Let $H\operatorname{char}G$", but instead write something like "Let $H\operatorname{char}G$ be a characteristic subgroup of $G$". However, personally I would not use this notation the notation unless it is *really* necessary and just write "Let $H\leq G$ be a characteristic subgroup of $G$".

Comment: I'd suggest $H\underset{\mathrm{char}}{\lhd}G$. It makes it clear that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and then clear that it's meant to be characteristic.

Comment: @user1729, sometimes it is convinient to write sometithing as $H \operatorname{char} N \vartriangleleft G$ so $H \vartriangleleft G$

Comment: Yes, I know. My point really is that you need to think hard about whether you actually need to use a notation. (And even if you do you should still be backing it up with words, "as $H$ is a characteristic subgroup of a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ it follows that $H\lhd G$".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen $N\triangleleft G$ for normal subgroups and $N\blacktriangleleft G$ for characteristic subgroups. This also makes clear that a characteristic subgroup is normal.

Comment: There is a potential issue here that if someone is just flicking through a paper than they might just assume that this notation meant "normal".

Comment: @user1729 Yes, you are right, there are also several arguments against it, like that it is not used by many people, but I find it different enough from normal subgroup, because it is filled with black.

Comment: I will use this notation in my notes)

Answer (score 2):

There is no common notation for this subgroup, in the sense, not all algebra text has a common notation. However, some authors use H char G to denote H is the characteristic subgroup of G. For example, Dummit and Foote use this notation. Also from the comment, Rotman use this notation. So from now on, use this notation. There's no problem!